# user has_many :orders association but user.orders can not be found in the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

my repo shows below:
https://github.com/Gtar69/artstore_hw2

Error Message: 
/Users/Gtar/project2/artstore-store-v1/app/models/order.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

```
Extracted source (around line #22):
     def checkout  
        #if !current_user
         @order = current_user.orders.build 
         @info = @order.build_info
        #else 
         # redirect_to carts_path

Rails.root: /Users/Gtar/project2/artstore-store-v1
```

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:22:in `checkout'
Request

I met a question that webpage can not refer to user.orders. I'm pretty sure current_user in the code works and declaration of in model/user.rb and model/order.rb make has_one association well.

My logic in the project is to 
in carts/index.html using checkout defined on carts_controller.rb to render a payment information form. For checkout function, it used current_user.orders to 
build a new order collect in the current_user.orders.

However, it seems that current_user.orders doesn't exit (also in the rails council) !! need some medicine to solve the issue~~~ Thanks!!!

Comment: what does you current_user method says?

Comment: ok got it. you are missing `end` statement in your `order` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items, :class_name => "OrderItem", :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :info, :class_name => "OrderInfo", :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :info


  def build_item_cache_from_cart(cart)
    cart.items.each do |cart_item|
      item = items.build
      item.product_name = cart_item.title
      item.quantity = 1
      item.price = cart_item.price
      item.save
    end
  end

  def calculate_total!(current_cart)
    self.total = current_cart.total_price
    self.save
  end
end
```

Comment: @user3546176 No problem. Please if problem solved accept the answer and mark is usefull :) happy programming